# Image Plane or Object Plane Scanning Satellite Instruments

Tags: modis, satellite, sentinel-3

Scanning systems can be classified as either Image Plane or Object Plane, depending on where the light rays converge, as shown in the following figure.

[image]

I would like to know if the Terra MODIS, Sentinel 3 SLSTR and Sentinel 3 OLCI Instruments are Image Plane or an Object Plane Scanning sensors. I couldn't find anything on the corresponding official sites.